# SQL how to select certain number of data each time in reverse order

Tags: mysql, sql

how to select 2 data each time from mysql database in reverse order. For example, in this table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |     category     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          6          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          7          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to select 2 data each time where category is 1 in reverse order.
For first time running of query, I will get data of id =7 and id =5. For second time running of query, I will get data of id =3 and id =1. How to form that query?

Comment: First time? Can you just post the desired result?

Comment: I mean if I run the sql query first time will get result of id=7 and id=5. Second time will get id=3 and id=1. However, I dont know how to write that query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different (by limit) queries for that:

```
select id from [your-table-name-here] where category=1 order by id desc limit 0, 2 --to get first two
select id from [your-table-name-here] where category=1 order by id desc limit 2, 2 --to get next two
...
select id from [your-table-name-here] where category=1 order by id desc limit x, x+2 --etc
```

Comment: @ serhiyb is this in reverse id order?

Comment: Added reverse order.

Comment: The limit will change to reverse order also when put order by id desc. This is the accept answer

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use another language in addition to SQL to do this. Here is an example using PHP:

```
$query_string = "SELECT `id` FROM `<TABLE NAME>` WHERE `category` = 1 ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query_string); //where $link stores the connection to your MySQL database

if ($result != null) {

    $highest_id = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];

    $second_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    if ($second_row != null) $second_highest_id = $second_row[0];
}

//etc
```

Comment: The performance will be very slow if the database is large. I think this can be done by using limit but not sure how to form the exact query

Comment: The chosen answer will require more calls to the database though. I guess it depends on how many rows you expect to have to check.